# how to snap together columns to a new table in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 365 v2210 build 15726.20262

I would like to use a formula to combine two columns together.
Here is what I've tried:

```
=LET(
    alpha,
    Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,

    bravo,
    Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,

    combine_columns,
    LAMBDA(first,second,
        CHOOSE(
            TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(first) + COLUMNS(second))),
            first,
            second
        )
    ),

    combine_columns(bravo, alpha)
 )
```

Given the input

*Sheet1*

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |

*Sheet2*

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

I want the output

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | 1 |
| 5 | 8 | 2 |
| 6 | 9 | 3 |

The output I actually get is

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | #VALUE! |
| 5 | 2 | #VALUE! |
| 6 | 3 | #VALUE! |

Can anybody suggest how to get the result I'm after?

Comment: I can't really distinguish the transformation between the input and output, since they look the same. Please edit your question to more clearly show what transformation you are trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to keep things simple for a trivial example, though I may have accidentally made them more confusing. They should look the same. I want to reproduce that table by taking column A and sticking it to column B & C.   In a non-trivial example, column A might be in a different sheet than columns B&C or might be the result of some other transformation. 
I've updated the example to show some trivial transformation.

Comment: updated so the input and output no longer look the same.

Comment: you should have access to `HSTACK()`

Comment: @PaulH ,,,, my simple suggestion **NEVER TRY TO MAKE THE JOB UNNECESSARILY COMPLICATED** ,,,,, ☺

Comment: @gns100 - `HSTACK()` is the answer I needed. Thank you. If you put it in to an answer, I will accept.

Comment: @PaulH, glad it was what you were looking for. I suggest you create and accept your own answer, as I probably couldn't put in an adequate answer. I would like to see how you use it in your use case. I'm sure I can learn from how you used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@gns100 taught me a new function, [`HSTACK()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2), which does exactly what I needed.

```
=LET(
    alpha,
    Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,

    bravo,
    Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,

    HSTACK(bravo, alpha)
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your example is overly simplistic, but it appears you are just moving Column A to Column C. You can do that simply with:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$3,SEQUENCE(3),{2,3,1})
```

[image]

Comment: Nice & working +10 ☺

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I really am trying to snap together two columns. I will update the example to be less trivial.